# PHP - Issues with session variables

Tags: php, ajax, session-variables

I'm having an issue on my website. I'm not posting any code because I don't think there is anything relevant to show and I've done things alike several times. My question is just about logic.

I have a page that sends ajax requests to two other php files. These files use session variables to build some JSON.

The problem is some session variables are seen only by one php file. When I check the output of `var_dump($_SESSION)` I can see that one file sees all the session variables, and the other one can only see the ones it has set in the previous calls. When I check the session IDs, I can see that both files have different session IDs.

Do you have any idea about what could be the problem, or just tracks to follow?

Comment: different session IDs means the session cookie settings are incorrect and the browser's not sending the cookie set in page `A` along with requests for page `B`, causing page `B` to create an entirely new session.

Comment: @MarcB How do I fix that?

Comment: @André use start_session() at the top of the pages where you are setting and getting session variable if this is not then post your error

Comment: Thanks @HaiderAli for your answer, but I already fixed the the problem (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it. The problem was linked to the domain name. When you use subdomains, or don't add "www", the browser thinks it's a different domain and doesn't send the cookies, then a new session is initiated.

Answer (score 0):

check whether you have `session_start()` in both pages before using the sission variables

Comment: Yes, that's the first instruction on each file.

Comment: Are the [session configuration values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php) set to the same value in each file ?

Comment: @F.C. I haven't edited them, so I think they are the same as default.

Comment: @Bolli No I'm not using Drupal or any other CMS.